# How do I get an ASP.Net MVC application running on my host?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

Is there something special you usually have to do? I have a DailyRazor .Net Starter account, but it won't run my MVC app. Any ideas?

I have contacted support but they said it should work, but it's not... Thought maybe someone here could help me faster.

Comment: Well I was getting something like Resource not Found or something like that, though now I'm getting this: "CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"... but that should definitely be in the GAC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been through this with Gearhost.

Your host needs to install the following on your IIS server:

- [ASP.NET 3.5 **SP1**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en)
- [ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)

They need to enable the following settings:

If it's running **IIS 6** on Windows 2003:

- **Enable Wildcard Mappings**: ([1](http://helios.ca/2009/06/23/deploying-asp-net-mvc-application-under-iis6/)), ([2](http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/))

If it's running IIS 7 on Windows 2008, then you don't need to do anything.

**Edit:**

> Regarding your `Linq` error; that means they probably don't have the correct version of the .NET Framework installed. I'd open a ticket and ask them.  If they seem unwilling to help or to upgrade your server, there are plenty of hosts that will, and I can make recommendations if you'd like.

Comment: Would you please make recommendations? I'd like something fairly cheap, but I'm willing to pay a little more for a good host. I'm going to email them and see what they'll do for me though first.

Comment: I can't recommend Gearhost (http://gearhost.com) enough. I use them for my ASP.NET MVC web applications; they have fantastic support, and they're more than willing to help out their customers.

Comment: looks like i'll be switching hosts

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the host does not have the latest version of the .net framework installed (3.5) , or if they do, your web application is perhaps set up to use an older version of asp.net.

Also, if they happen to be running on IIS6, there are a few extra steps they may have to do:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the MVC assemblies (System.Web. Abstractions, MVC, and Routing) to your Bin folder.

Comment: Visual Studio put them there automatically when I published the application.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your error, you can try adding the System.Linq dll to your bin folder to see if that gets rid of that error.  Does your host have .NET 3.5 installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy `System.Core.dll` to your Bin folder.

Alternatively, ask DailyRazor to install .Net 3.5.  (They might not listen, though)